# combining many sql tables with joins-most efficient method

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 6 tables where i would like to join most of them to get 1 View.

```
   fb_stats
    -------------
    -fb_Account_id # these fb account ids range from 1-8
    -num_likes
    -date

    fb_account
    -------------
    -fb_account_id 
    -fb_account_name # the name of the fb account ids (8 of them)
    -date

    twt_stats
    ------------
    -twt_Account_id # these twt account ids range from 1-11
    -num_followers 
    -date

    twt_account
    ------------
    -twt_Account_id
    -twt_account_name # these twt account_names correspond to the twt account id ranging from          
    -date               1-11

    ga_1                # this is the fb_account_name of one of the fb accounts and it has          
                          fb_Account_id=3. It is also the twt_account_name with     
                           twt_account_id=5
    -----------
    -unique_visits_1
    -date


    ga_2                 # this is the fb_account_name of one of the fb accounts and it has           
                           fb_Account_id=2. It is also the twt_account_name with          
                           twt_account_id=7
    ------------
    -unique_visits_2
    -date

Given that date is the only common factor in all 6 tables, while table ga_1 and ga_2 are subsets of accounts in the first 4 tables, how can i create a view with this fields?

New View
----------------
-date
-fb_Account_id 
-fb_Account_name
-num_likes
-num_followers
-unique_visits
```

So in order for this table to be created and display the field unique visits, we must show `fb_account_id 3 = twt_account_id 5 for 1 row`

```
fb_account_id 2 = twt_account_id 7 for the next row

Example table
--------------
date      fb_account_id    fb_account_name  num_likes  num_followers  uniqueVisit
04-18-14       3                 Ga1            100           1000        600

01-01-13       10                Ga9              30            800        NULL
```

My method was to add one more column in ga1 and ga2 where it has a column with id = all 3 or all 2 so it can join to the fb_account_id or tweet_account_id on those id.

```
USE `my_database`;
CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `total_audience` AS
Select 
date(fb_stats.date) as Date,
fb_stats.num_likes AS fb_likes,
fb_stats.fb_account_id AS fb_acct,
twt_stats.num_followers AS twt_followers,
twt.account_id AS tweet_acct
FROM
fb_stats 
Join 
twt_stats 
ON twt_stats.date=date(fb_stats.date)
  .
  .
```

Comment: Try not to using views...

Comment: how else? I need a table